# Issue with code generation in .NET 5.0 with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm having issues when creating an API Controller in .NET 5.0 with Entity Framework Core.

Here's what I'm doing:

- I'm using .NET 5.0
- Installed the Entity Framework Core packages and all 3 have the version 5.0

[image]

- The model and DataContext classes have already been created and using them had already created a table in the database earlier
- However when I *right-click on the API project, click on Controller > Select "API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" > Select "Model Class" & "DataContext class" > Enter the name of the controller*
- I keep getting the error

> There was an error running the selected code generator: Package restore failed. Rolling back the changes for API

[image]

Troubleshooting done:

- Cleared the NuGet Cache in *Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)*
- Made sure that the Entity Framework Core packages and the .net version are the same in the .csproj

[image]

What am I missing here that is causing the issue?

Comment: Do you have any other project apart from `API`? Have you tried installing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`?

Comment: @dglozano No, I haven't got any other project with the same name API. I also installed Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design for this project and tried again. Still the same error message

Comment: I meant any other project at all in the same solution, that might have a mismatch in the versioo being used

Comment: Apart from the API, there is only an UI project in the solution and it uses the same .NET version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed the latest version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package, you probably got version `5.0.2`. That package cannot generate code based on Entity Framework Core packages of version `5.0.0`.

From my experience - to generate EF Core based code, the version of your `Design` package should be equal to or less than the version of your `EF Core` packages. So, you need to either upgrade the `EF Core` packages, or install the version `5.0.0` of the `Design` package.

**EDIT:**
I faced the same issue and it was resolved after upgrading the `EF Core` packages, which is `5.0.4` currently, and installing the latest `Design` package, which is `5.0.2` currently.

Comment: I tried installing the versions `5.0.0` and `3.1.5` of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` , still getting the same error

Comment: @Scorpio Install the latest EF Core packages (5.0.4) and the latest `CodeGeneration.Design` package (5.0.2). Then try again. I faced the same issue and it was resolved after adjusting the package versions the way I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Awesome!! It is working fine after I upgraded the EF Core packages to `5.0.4`. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, then you should mark it as accepted, so that future users/visitors with same issue know that this solution works.

Comment: @atiyar   You saved my life!! I was Googling all day for the answer and turned to Stackoverflow. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my case to generate EF core based code, i need to installed version **5.0.13** of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** and version **5.0.12** of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** and  **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**
and version **5.0.2** of **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design**

*Note:- Make sure to clear Nuget Cache*